# problem during update

Tags: updates, logging

I tryed updating my ubuntu to the new version today, and it suddenly crashed. I then just had to reboot in mid-installation. Now i cannot even log in anymore, it just shows the hour on top of the screen and it is not giving me the option to log in. 
Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try going in to a shell by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and login with your user name and pass, then type `sudo do-release-upgrade` and follow the instructions. That will hopefully try to resume the upgrade.

If it's says `No new release found` then try `sudo apt-get upgrade` and follow the instructions. That will try to fix the broken packages.

Hope it helps.